# Ansible error - implementation error: unknown type string requested for name

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I am getting the unknown type string error when I execute the ansible playbook

> implementation error: unknown type string requested for name

I am trying to display my name using a ansible playbook. The bg code is python.

```
---
-  name:  Test hello module
   hosts:  localhost

   tasks:
     -  name:  run the hello module
        hello:
          name: 'Test'
        register:  helloout

     -  name:  dump test output
        debug:
          msg:  '{{ helloout  }}'
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python


def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(
                argument_spec=dict(
                        name=dict(required=True, type='string')
                ),
        supports_check_mode=False
        )
        name = module.params['name']
        module.exit.json(changed=False, meta=name)

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [Test hello module] ****************************************************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [run the hello module] *************************************************************************************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "implementation error: unknown type string requested for name"}
>
> PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************
>   localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `AnsibleModule()` method argument `argument_spec`, the type you are looking for is actually `str` and not `string`:

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        name=dict(required=True, type='str')
    ),
    supports_check_mode=False
)
```

You can see the list of accepted type specifications for the argument in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#type).